# Avro python array serialization

Tags: python, serialization, avro

Looks like the following doesn't fit avro schema:

```
[{'page_title': 'Antoine Meillet', 'page_id': 3, 'contributors': [['contribution', {'revisions': 2, 'username': 'Curry'}], ['contribution', {'revisions': 1, 'username': 'script de conversion'}], ['contribution', {'revisions': 1, 'username': 'Francis'}]]}]
```

Schema :

```
    {
  "namespace": "org.wikipedia.fr",
  "name": "meta-history",
  "type": "record",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "page_title",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "page_id",
      "type": "int"
    },
    {
      "name": "contributors",
      "type": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
          "type": "record",
          "name": "contribution",
          "fields": [
            {
              "name": "revisions",
              "type": "int"
            },
            {
              "name": "username",
              "type": "string"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Got "ValueError: no value and no default for revisions"

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, not needed to name the array field.

[{'page_title': 'Antoine Meillet', 'page_id': 3, 'contributors': [{'revisions': 2, 'username': 'Curry'}, {'revisions': 1, 'username': 'script de conversion'}, {'revisions': 1, 'username': 'Francis'}]]

Got it right.